# Integrating $\int x+1 \, dx$ using $u$-substition gives wrong answer.

Tags: calculus

$\int (x+1) dx$

Substituting:

$u = x + 1$ and $du = dx$

$$\int u \,du = \frac{u^2}{2}$$

Which gives:

$$\int (x+1) \, dx = \frac{(x+1)^2}{2}$$

This is completely wrong as the correct answer is $\frac{x^2}{2}+x$

Why did this happen?

Comment: What's the difference of $(x+1)^2/2$ and $x^2/2+x$?

Comment: It should be $\int (x+1)dx=\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}+C$.

Comment: you missed the +C

Comment: @CameronBuie It is likely a typo for $\frac{x^2}{2} + 2x$, with the wrong braces used.

Comment: It is *completely right*, rather than wrong; *a* correct answer is $\frac{x^2}{2}+x$, in the sense this is an antiderivative, but $\frac{(x+1)^2}{2}$ is an antiderivative as well.

Comment: @CameronBuie Sorry, but I typed it on a device that doesn't render MathJax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you expand your second answer, you get
$$ \frac{(x+1)^2}{2} = \frac{x^2}{2} + x + \frac{1}{2}. $$
This differs from the "correct" answer by a constant.  But if two functions differ by a constant, they will have the same derivative.  Hence both answers are equally correct (or incorrect).  I submit that a truly correct answer would be
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} + x + C
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
\frac{(x+1)^2}{2} + C, $$
where $C$ is a real constant.

---

Addendum:  I have a stupid trick for getting my students to remember the constant.  We have
$$ \int \frac{1}{\text{cabin}} \, \mathrm{d}(\text{cabin}) = \text{house boat}.$$
Why?

Remember that
$$ \int \frac{1}{x}\, \mathrm{d}x = \log|x| + C. $$
Thus
$$ \int \frac{1}{\text{cabin}} \, \mathrm{d}(\text{cabin})
= \log|\text{cabin}| + \text{sea}, $$
which is quite clearly a house boat.

Answer (score 5):

You forgot the constant C. It is very important:

$$
\int u du = \frac{u^2}{2} + C = \frac{(x+1)^2}{2} + C = \frac{x^2}{2} + x + \frac{1}{2}+ C = \frac{x^2}{2} + x + C'
$$

Answer (score 0):

Both answers are right: $\displaystyle \frac{(x+1)^2} 2 = \frac{x^2 + 2x + 1} 2 = \frac {x^2} 2 + x + \text{constant}$